# Why triggers try to insert NULL value when using a field from 'inserted' table?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have to sync changes done in MSSQL with a remote MySQL database. The changes to be synced are adding invoices and users to the system. The remote server is not expected to be always reachable so I'm trying to set up a kind of log table for storing changes done in MSSQL.

Here is a fully working trigger for that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[dokument_insert]
   ON [dbo].[dokument]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [bcg_ekodu].[dbo].[sync_stack] (event,sql, table_name, import_priority)
        SELECT 
            'INSERT',
            'INSERT INTO bills SET
                date = "'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),dok_kuup,120)+'", 
                total = "'+CAST(kokkusum AS nvarchar)+'",
                number = "'+RTRIM(dok_nr)+'", 
                created = "'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),savetime,120)+'", 
                rounded = "'+CAST(ymardus AS nvarchar)+'",
                currency = "'+CAST(valuuta AS nvarchar)+'", 
                due_date = "'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),tasupaev,120)+'", 
                pk_joosep = "'+CAST(dok_kood AS nvarchar)+'",
                joosep_hankija = "'+CAST(hankija AS nvarchar)+'";
             UPDATE
                bills, users, companies 
             SET 
                bills.user_id = users.id,
                bills.imported = NOW()
             WHERE
                bills.imported IS NULL
                AND companies.id = users.company_id
                AND companies.pk_joosep = 10
                AND bills.user_id = users.pk_joosep',
            'bills',
            '200'
        FROM inserted
END
```

It inserts a row into 'sync_stack' table every time a row is inserted to 'dokument' table. The 'sql' column will contain an SQL to create the same kind of row in another (MySQL) database.

But this trigger is not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[klient_insert]
   ON [dbo].[klient]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [bcg_ekodu].[dbo].[sync_stack] (event,sql, table_name, import_priority)
        SELECT 
            'INSERT',
            'INSERT INTO users SET
                username =10'+CAST(kl_kood as nvarchar)+',
                password = NULL,
                name ="'+LTRIM(RTRIM(kl_nimi))+'",  
                email ="'+CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(kl_email)) as nvarchar)+'",  
                reference_no ="'+CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(kl_viide)) as nvarchar)+'",   
                phone ="'+CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(kl_tel1)) as nvarchar)+'",   
                logins ="'+CAST(0 as nvarchar)+'",  
                last_login = NULL,  
                created ="'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),savetime,120)+'",   
                updated = NULL, 
                deleted ="0",   
                address ="'+CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(kl_aadr1)) as nvarchar)+'",    
                pk_joosep ="'+CAST(kl_kood as nvarchar)+'"',
            'users',
            '210'
        FROM inserted
END
```

While the execution of the above SQL to create that trigger completes just fine, when I try to insert some rows to the 'triggered' table, I get the following error:

```
No row was updated.

The data in row 175 was not committed.
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Error Message: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'sql', table 'mydb.dbo.sync_stack'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The statement has been terminated.

Correct the errors and retry or press ESC to cancel the change(s).
```

- If I delete this trigger, this error does not occur.
- If I insert just plain text for 'sql' column, it works as expected.
- If I use any field from the inserted row, even just a text field, it fails again.
- If I allow NULL values in 'sql' column, inserting rows succeeds but I get a NULL value in 'sql' column.

How to make the second trigger work as expected, too?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Concatenating any value to NULL is NULL:

```
select 'test' + NULL
```

Results in null, you should use something like that for your columns:

```
select isnull(column, '')
```

This would result in an empty string.

Comment: I think you have an unwarranted bias against COALESCE. I wrote this article 7 years ago: http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html If you read thoroughly you will see that the only performance issue with COALESCE is when one of the expressions involves a subquery. The question at hand does not involve a subquery. Therefore I think your down-vote of my answer was short-sighted and serves little purpose - you're making bold, generic statements that are actually not true, but that unsuspecting users are going to believe because your answer was accepted. A shame.

Comment: Let's say "column" is char(3) (a currency code) and you want to use "UNKNOWN" when NULL. ISNULL will give "UNK". COALESCE will give "UNKNOWN". ISNULL isn't *correct* in the way you mean which appears to be "always". http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4277/630

Comment: For this particular purpose, I think ISNULL is actually a better fit. Currently I'm doing CAST( LTRIM( RTRIM( ISNULL(kl_nimi,  'NULL') ) ) as nvarchar(4000) ). That is, I want to display the string 'NULL' if the field is null. I'm not entirely sure whether I should use ISNULL directly around the field or around CAST() though.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "better fit"? You'd rather use a non-standard proprietary function because some guy says it's better? When you're nesting all of these functions against the column, I don't think it really matters what order you apply them... however there is information missing. What is the data type of `kl_nimi`?

Answer (score 8):

I suspect that at least one of the values from inserted that you are concatenating into your SQL statement is `NULL`. You can circumvent this by using `COALESCE`, e.g.

```
username =10'+COALESCE(CAST(kl_kood as nvarchar), '')+',
```

Of course you shouldn't be declaring `nvarchar` without specifying a length, right?

- [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that nvarchar should have a length specified to protect against truncating values to 30 chars. I did not know that.

Comment: @PhilippMehrwald I'm sorry, but what advantage does ISNULL have over COALESCE? COALESCE is ANSI standard while many people confuse ISNULL with its VB-related cousin that works differently. COALESCE also supports more than two arguments. So why is this a -1?

Comment: COALESCE is slower than ISNULL, microsoft is suggesting to use ISNULL when even you can use it instead of COALESCE.

Comment: Can you provide an official reference where I can read about this suggestion from Microsoft? Are you going to go around and down-vote all answers that mention COALESCE, or just answers that compete with yours?

Comment: @PhilippMehrwald: COALESCE and ISNULL behave the same when the datatypes involved are the same. Do you have an authoritative Microsoft reference to back up your assertion? See my answer on dba.se about this exact thing http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4277/630